# Turn array into array of arrays following structure of another array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to turn an array into an array of arrays following another array of arrays.  I'm not sure how to do this, here are the arrays:

```
orig_array = [[0,1],[4],[3],[],[3,2,6],[]]
my_array = [2,0,1,3,3,4,5]

wanted_array = [[2,0],[1],[3],[],[3,4,5],[]]
```

I would like to keep the empty arrays.

Thanks

Comment: What's the significance of the `numpy` tag?  It looks like you have lists; list of list, but still lists.  Even if `orig_array` is a numpy array, it is object type, and basically a list.

Comment: @user2520932 if one of the below answers helped you, please consider marking it as accepted. This will give reputation to the answerer (making answering worth their while), and at the same time indicate that your question is already answered. While we're at it: you should also consider upvoting questions and answers that you find useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the lengths of each element in `orig_array`, perform cumumlative summations along the length values to give us the indices at which `my_array` needs to be split and finally use `np.split` to actually perform the splitting. Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
lens = [len(item) for item in orig_array]
out = np.split(my_array,np.cumsum(lens))[:-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [72]: orig_array = np.array([[0,1],[4],[3],[],[3,2,6],[]])
    ...: my_array = np.array([2,0,1,3,3,4,5])
    ...: 

In [73]: lens = [len(item) for item in orig_array]
    ...: out = np.split(my_array,np.cumsum(lens))[:-1]
    ...: 

In [74]: out
Out[74]: 
[array([2, 0]),
 array([1]),
 array([3]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([3, 4, 5]),
 array([], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: @MartinHallén `my_array` is just used for extracting elements from. So, should not be dependent if its sorted or not.

Comment: Sorry, edited question to better reflect actual my_array

Comment: You are right. Requires numpy, but nice solution. Have my upvote :)

Comment: @user2520932 Edited sample run to showcase usage with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def do(format, values):
    if type(format) == list:
        return [do(v, values) for v in format]
    else:
        return values.pop(0)

print do(orig_array, my_array)
```

Note: this destroys the array where the values come from.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
import copy

def reflect_array(orig_array, order):
    wanted_array = copy.deepcopy(orig_array)
    for i, part_list in enumerate(orig_array):
        for j, _ in enumerate(part_list):
            wanted_array[i][j] = order.pop()
    return wanted_array
```

Test run:

```
orig_array = [[0,1],[4],[3],[],[3,2,6],[]]
my_array = [2,0,1,3,3,4,5]

print reflect_array(orig_array, my_array)
# [[2, 0], [1], [3], [], [3, 4, 5], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [858]: my_array = [2,0,1,3,3,4,5]

In [859]: [[my_array.pop(0) for _ in range(len(x))] for x in orig_array]
Out[859]: [[2, 0], [1], [3], [], [3, 4, 5], []]
```

Use `b=my_array[:]` if you don't want to change `my_array`.

This operates on the same principle as `@karoly's` answer; just more direct because it assumes only one level of nesting.